# Suppress notice when passed array is a key and not array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple function which should check if the passed in parameter is an array and has values. The function works perfectly except in the event when I pass a multi-dimensional array as the property. I suspect the isset() passes but because the key may possibly not exist it gives an undefined:

```
 <?php
 $array1 = array("John","Doe");
 $array2 = array();

 function valid_array($array) {
     if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }

 // Below works great:
 valid_array($array1);

 // If I pass the following I get the notice 
 // Notice: Undefined index: sample_key in ....:
 valid_array($array2['sample_key']);     


 ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And why would you want to suppress the notice? It warns you about incorrect usage, which btw happens outside of your function. It's the invalid array access when trying to invoke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means, there is no array item as `sample_key` as its key. Use `isset()` to verify that, don't suppress it.

```
if(isset($array2['sample_key'])) 
    valid_array($array2['sample_key']);
```

Such cases are called `Exceptions` catch them and throw an error instead.

Here is a way to raise an error upon use.

```
function valid_array(array $array) {
                 //    ^ Asks for a generic array to be passed
     if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to suppress an error is by using the '@' symbol before the function is called:

Example: `@my_custom_function();`
This will suppress any errors your function might churn out (but it will not fix them)